# How to get value of specific column like 'id' With onClick event on table's row with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get Value of ID column using javascript onclick event on row With Following Code

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
   </tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>john</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Anything you tried..or Googled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){

  alert(this.getElementsByTagName("th")[0].innerHTML);

});
```